# Получение Root прав Android

Tags: java, android, взлом

Мне необходимо получить Root права на андроид . 
Я знаю что есть много приложений , предназначенных для получения root, но в моем случае мне нужно написать свое приложение которое рутит Android. 
Возможно ли это ? Мне нужны ссылки на исходный код данного приложения.

Comment: Раз есть много приложений, то возможно. Написал же их кто-то.

Comment: начинайте изучать ядро